# I have to show all the rows in my query - where's my mistake?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public Section SectionView(object id, SqlConnection conn)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
            conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("TMR_SECTION_VIEW", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("data", conn);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "TMR_SECTION_VIEW";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sectionID", id.ToString);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

        sqlda.Fill(dtbl);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return id;
    }
}
```

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TMR_SECTION_VIEW]
    @sectionID int, @name varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Section 
    WHERE sectionid = @sectionID 
END
```

Comment: i guess `cmd` couldn't understand that `CommandType` is `StoredProcedure` that's why you have to tell it twice.

Comment: What problem you are facing? What do you expect out of this code? Can you explain code and tell us what is happening and what should have happend?

Comment: im only getting errors at cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sectionID", id.ToString);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i want to show all the data in my rows using section id

Comment: im getting the error at id.string ( return a string that represents the current object) and at "@name, name im getting (the name does not exist in the current context

Comment: what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: You don't have `name` variable defined anywhere also it should be `id.ToString()`. That's what is the problem...

Comment: thankyou i think that has fixed it

Comment: Why are you calling your **stored procedure** `..._View` ?!?!?!? That seems to be totally against the *Principle of Least Surprise* - if something is called ` ......View` , everyone I know would expect it to be a **view** - not a stored procedure......

Answer (score 1):

You have things a little bit out of order...

You should be specifying the command name on the SqlCommand (not the DataAdapter) and you should be telling the DataAdapter to use the SqlCommand.

I'd change this to allow you to specify the Stored Procedure name as a parameter when you call the function:

```
public Section SectionView(object id, SqlConnection conn, string sql = String.Empty)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sql))
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();                

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sectionID", id.ToString);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter
                { SelectCommand = cmd };

            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sqlda.Fill(dtbl);
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

You duplicated a lot of things (like setting the CommandType of your SqlCommand) and you created DataTable `dt` without using it, so I removed it from the sample in my answer.

So what's happening here is that you're specifying a sql string as a parameter (which can be a normal SQL query or a stored procedure) and you're building a `SqlCommand` with it that has parameters.

Using that SqlCommand, you're creating a DataAdapter having the SqlCommand as its SelectCommand and then you're using that DataAdapter to fill the DataTable.

**NOTE:** You don't need to execute `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` when retrieving data as the `DataAdapter.Fill()` function basically does that for you.

ExecuteNonQuery would be useful when inserting or updating data - not when reading data.